# Python pywin32 Adding Excel Object, IconLabel not displaying

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pywin32, sys, ole-object

I am using pywin32 module to add an excel file as an object in another excel file, I need to get the label added to it as Europe in the object. Even after adding the parameter IconLabel in code, I don't see any caption in the object attached to Excel, can anyone please let me know what is wrong in the code?

Here is the following Code I have used:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import sys
Filename=str(sys.argv[1])
Sheetname=str(sys.argv[2])
Filename2=str(sys.argv[3])
xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb=xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename)
ws=wb.Worksheets(Sheetname)
dest_cell=ws.Range("A1")
obj = ws.OLEObjects()
obj.Add(Filename=Filename2,Link=False,DisplayAsIcon=True,IconLabel="Europe",Left=dest_cell.Left,Top=dest_cell.Top)
wb.Save()
xl.Application.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

你好，我经过测试，在Excel 2021版本的Excel测试成功：
Embedded_object = worksheet.OLEObjects()

Embedded_object.Add(ClassType=None, Filename=file_location, Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=True,IconLabel=worksheet.Cells(G, 7).Value,Left=left_index,Top = top_index,***IconFileName=r"C:\Windows\Installer{90160000-000F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe",IconIndex=0***)
#IconFileName参数和时必须的，不确定值的时候，请使用Excel的录制宏功能获取，IconIndex=0是固定的

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).